# Extract substring from string with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to extract MIB-Objects from snmpwalk output. The output `FILE` looks like:

```
RFC1213-MIB::sysDescr.0.0.0.0.192.168.1.2 = STRING: "Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u1 (2017-06-18) x86_64"
RFC1213-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: RFC1155-SMI::enterprises.8072.3.2.10
..
```

First, I read the output file, split at character `=` and remove everything between `RFC1213-MIB::` and `.0` till the end of the string.

```
while read -r; do echo "${REPLY%%=*}" | sed -e 's/RFC1213-MIB::\(.*\)\.0/\1/'; done <$FILE
```

My current output:

```
sysDescr.0.0.0.192.168.1.2 
sysObjectID
```

How can I remove the other values? Is there a better solution of extracting `sysDescr`, `sysObjectID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F[:.] '{print $3}'
```

*(define `:` and `.` as field delimiters and display the 3rd field)*

with sed (Gnu):

```
sed 's/^[^:]*::\|\.0.*//g'
```

*(replace with the empty string all that isn't a `:` followed by `::` at the start of the line or the first `.0` and following characters until the end of the line)*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with:

```
sed 's/RFC1213-MIB::\([^\.]*\).*/\1/' $FILE
```

This will get everything that is not a dot (`.`) following the `RFC1213-MIB::` string.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use sed, you can just use parameter substitution. sed is an external process so it won't be as fast as parameter substitution since it's a bash built in.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do line=${line#*::}; line=${line%%.*}; echo $line; done < file
```

`line=${line#*::}` assumes `RFC1213-MIB` does not have two colons and will be split from `sysDescr` with two colons.

`line=${line%%.*}` assumes `sysDescr` will have a `.` after it.

If you have more examples, that you think won't work, I can update my answer.